# Using ESRI character font ("Environmental & Icons") with formatting tag in layout text box

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, font

I am attempting to use a character from the ESRI Environmental & Icons font collection (A bird in particular). I went into my character map tool and found the one I want (symbol right parenthesis). With the formatting tags, the input looks like this:

```
<BOL>Country Y</BOL><FNT name="ESRI Environmental & Icons">  )</FNT>
Disease X
Total Avian Cases: 12,345
<FNT size="8">Since:  01 JAN 2016 </FNT>
```

[image: Character Map]

I had no problems using a different character set (ESRI US Forestry 1, for example). I suspect it has something to do with the "&" in the font title.
I also tried using "ESRI Environmental & Icons Regular," which is how it's listed in the font folder on my system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `&amp;` instead of `&`

```html
<BOL>Country Y</BOL><FNT name="ESRI Environmental &amp; Icons">  )</FNT>
Disease X
Total Avian Cases: 12,345
<FNT size="8">Since:  01 JAN 2016 </FNT>
```